# ADB shell and ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, adb

Trying to write a small ruby script to automate some tedious stuff I currently do manually in windows command prompt.

Pseudo code:

system "adb kill-server"

system "adb start-server"

system "adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx"

system "adb shell"

This is where I am stuck.

At the adb shell prompt, I want to:

cd to/some/directory

rm a bunch of files

Inside my ruby script, how do I insert the cd command at the adb shell prompt?
And then insert rm command at adb shell prompt.

I tried "system" with no effect.  I assume "system" only works to communicate with the windows command prompt, and not the adb shell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

system "adb kill-server"
system "adb start-server"
system "adb connect 192.168.xxx.xxx"
PTY.spawn("adb shell") do |output, input, process_id|
  input.puts("cd /to/some/directory")
  input.puts("rm a-bunch-of-files")
  input.puts("exit")
end
```

Comment: pty doesn't work under windows, rubysl-pty used to with Ruby 1.9.3 but not in 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The PTY suggestion of user1835175 would be great if it had a working windows equivalent. Tried rubysl-pty under Windows7/Ruby 2.3.0 in a ConEmu Bash console but didn't work, you could make a new question how to install it in Windows.

I did something like what you are asking in another terminal using Autoit.
It has it's own scripting language but you can use it from Ruby also.

You can use it in Ruby like the following, (it can be simpler but I needed mouse controll also), see other examples but this is the code that worked for me..

```
require 'win32ole'

# AutoIt3 needs to be installed
app = "Adb" 
appClass = "[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]"    # retrieved with AutoIt Window Info 
ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
ai.WinActivate(appClass)
handle = "[HANDLE:#{ai.wingethandle(appClass)}]" 
ai.Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0)
ai.Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4)

ai.Send('cd \somefolder')
ai.Send('{ENTER}')
...
```